# Google Play Game Services API has not been used in project

Tags: android, google-play-services

E/SignInIntentService(15080): Access Not Configured. Google Play Game Services API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/games/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

what is this number? 608941808256
in strings.xml I have

```html
    <string name="google_app_id">33681715070</string>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have defined your API key yourself in the strings.xml. The Google play services Gradle plugin defines it for you

Comment: Alright. Doesn't really address my comment since Eclipse can support Gradle projects, though

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 33681715070 to 608941808256.

Did you use an tutorial? Then 33681715070 is probably someone else's app id

Comment: yes I used a tutorial but in the menifest there was another app_id

Answer (score 0):

I realized that to test it, I need a signed apk